# Power BI :: Group By in Area Chart is not working

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

**GOAL:** In the Azure Cost Management you can group the costs by Meter Category:

[image]

I would like to do the same with Power BI

**PROBLEM:** I created a Meter Category group.

I try to apply that everywhere but the Area Chart is not sliced by it:

[image]

Where should I put the Group BY in an Area Chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have the wrong visual. Can you try this instead?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

should do steps in PowerQuery, see as attached gif:

seperated into two parts as one is too big to upload

Part1 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Cax.gif)

Part2 [image]

Comment: I'm sure it must work but I have too many data. This might not be the right solution for my scenario. But I gave you 1 point

Comment: ok let me see if other solutions in powerbi view with DAX.